# "other spoken languages" in graduate applications

Tags: graduate-school, application

I am noticing that many graduate applications require a "primary spoken language" and "other spoken language".

For the "other spoken language", do they mean you must be proficient in writing, speaking, and reading? What if you can only do one (and you may not even be great at it...)? Does that count?

**EDIT** What if I do not know any of the jargons used in my study in that language?

Comment: I guess it asks for what other languages you *can* speak

Comment: Well for one thing, I assume if the university's language of instruction isn't somewhere on at least one of the lists, that's a quick rejection.

Comment: In many forms I saw this question followed by "Choose your level of proficiency" with the options ranging from "can translate with a dictionary" to "fluent". I surmise that even if a formal request like that is absent in your application form, you still can list all languages you know to some reasonable extent and put your estimate of your current level in parentheses after each. This will be both honest and comprehensive.

Comment: @Nate Not necessarily. If we have a good applicant who doesn't speak English reasonably well, he is just obliged to take the ESL (English as a second language) courses for a year or so and cannot hold a TA position before completing them. Other universities may have different policies, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If they ask about *"spoken"* languages then it is about speaking, not about writing and reading.

This should not be a surprise depending on the area of research you are studying. It could impact those you will be working with or it could involve your research subjects. For example, if you want to study cross-cultural team dynamics specifically between fracophones and anglophones and you only speak English and you cannot communicate at all in French, then you are going to have some difficulty with your research.

If they do not ask you to qualify your speaking ability, then do not worry about it. If they do, then answer appropriately.

So, in short, yes, if you can speak one *other language* even if not well, it does count.

As a side note, I know plenty of people who speak zero *other languages.*

Comment: Hmmm... Isn't the meaning of the standard phrase "Do you speak English?" just "Is there any hope I can communicate with you using English?" I wouldn't take the word "spoken" so literally here. However, you may be right and I may be wrong.

Comment: How fluent should I be in that language? What if I don't know the jargons used in my study in that language?

Comment: @sidht I would hope they would include a way for you rate your level of proficiency but if they don't then I would say if you could carry on even a basic conversation I would include it. However, if they ask you to rank it (basic, intermediate, advanced, fluent, native) then use their ranking system.

Comment: @fedja, I agree on the meaning of the phrase, but I don't take the meaning in the original question the same way - I read "spoken" literally here.

Comment: @Chris H Certainly. That's why my last sentence is there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The application to my program explicitly asks candidates to list the language the foreign languages they know, as well as identify their skills in speaking, writing, and reading those languages on a poor/fair/good/very good/excellent basis. We also ask them to identify how long they've been learning the language. (The disconnect between how people evaluate themselves—particularly in writing—and the quality of their written statements of purpose is at times quite jarring, as you can imagine.)

However, I'd say that the purposes of such questions are the same: to see how well you are able to communicate in languages other than your "native tongue," or to see how proficient you are in the working language of the program, if you're attending an international program.

If they only ask about speaking, then they only want to know about speaking and oral comprehension; writing and reading don't enter into the equation. The same is true if they ask about "reading knowledge" of a language: if you can read it, they're not necessarily concerned about your ability to speak it. Requiring reading knowledge used to be the case, and often still is, in fields such as mathematics and chemistry, where much of the "classic" literature in the fields were in languages such as French, German, and Russian. Therefore, the ability to be able to read and understand papers in at least one of those languages was considered a necessary skill for doctoral students to acquire.